# How to construct skeleton from coordinates in C#?

Tags: c#, kinect

I have an array of `Vector3D`, which holds the coordinates of joints and I also know which joint the given set of coordinates belongs to. Is there any way to construct a `Skeleton` from this data?

Comment: please refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213034/Kinect-Getting-Started-Become-The-Incredible-Hulk

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do? You could say that a skeleton IS an array of Vector3D with associated joints...